# In Xcode account preferences how can I refresh the teams connected to my Apple ID?

Tags: xcode, apple-id

I have an AppleID connected to multiple Apple Developer teams. I was added to a new team which works correctly, i.e. I can switch to it on the developer website.

However in Xcode account preferences I can not find a way to update the list of teams I am member of, is there a way to refresh the teams list or do I have to remove and add my Apple ID to update the teams?

Comment: I voted to re-open this question, as even though the problem is not reproducible, it happens to a lot of people. I would add as an answer: Try logging out from the account in Xcode, then log back in.

Comment: Perfectly valid question, and it would be helpful to accumulate other answers to it.

Comment: EG., I found that it is not enough to be added as a team member in iTunes Connect, you must also be invited via the developer portal (apple.developer.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, I now suddenly see the other team in the list, after a few restarts of Xcode (and yes, I did try restarting Xcode already). 
Anyways, problem solved.